# (Recreating Dig Dug) Having trouble with my blacking out my divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to recreate Dig Dig. I have a function where it gets the location of my "avatar" and turns the div it is on to the color black. At the moment it is working to some degree. When I move the avatar the divs turn black in different spots and some rows can only be activated if I move the element in a straight line which leads it off the playable area. If I move it straight up or down some divs in the column activate while others are skipped. Below are the relevant code and I left a jsfiddle link to show. Thanks for the help and I apologize in advance if what I said is still confusing.

[jsfiddlelink](http://jsfiddle.net/eksourn/2qdb2f4p/)

JQUERY

```js
function blackoutSquare(row, col) {
  console.log('Blacking out %s,%s', row, col)
  $('.all div:nth-of-type(' + row + ') div:nth-child(' + col + ')')
    .addClass('black')
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  blackoutSquare(0, 0);
  docReady()
})
$()

function leftArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';

}

function upArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
}

function downArrowPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
  element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
}

function zKeyPressed() {
  var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
}

function updateSquares() {
  var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
  var blockwidth = 40;
  var blockheight = 50;
  var top = parseInt(element.style.top);
  var left = parseInt(element.style.left);

  var row = -1 + top / blockheight
  var col = left / blockwidth
  console.log('Got row: %s, col %s from top: %s and left: %s', row, col, top, left)
  blackoutSquare(Math.floor(row), Math.floor(col))
}

function moveSelection(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 65:
      leftArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 68:
      rightArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 87:
      upArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 83:
      downArrowPressed();
      break;
    case 90:
      zKeyPressed();
  }
  updateSquares()
};

function docReady() {

  window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
};
```

CSS

```
  .black {
          background-color:black !important;
}
  .row1 {
        width:500px;
      }
      .row1 div {
          display:inline-block;
          width:50px;
          height:40px;
          background-color:#0000FF;
          margin:0px;
          vertical-align: top;
        }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="row1">
            <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
            <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you put these inside a snippet. You know there is a snippet option in this page.

Comment: Oh that probably would have been wise. Sorry i'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: The problem happens because `blackoutSquare(Math.floor(row),Math.floor(col))` function parameters are wrong. What i mean is, in reality, you have actually 12 rows. But in your code there are only 4 rows. If you go up, you may see it on console as it jumps from **4,6** to **3,6** . What about **4,16** and **4,26** they are all missing. You can either create more rows or edit these parameters `var row = -1+ top/blockheight` to send to `blackoutSquare()` function. This is actually a math problem, and i am willing to try to solve this problem as soon as i find time.

Comment: Ok thank you for your input. I'll look into it.